# Mail function doesn't work if I execute the php script from a bat file

Tags: php, email, batch-file

Here, is my php script :

[image]

my php.ini:

[image]

if I execute the script using a browser, it works fine :

[image]

but if I execute the script using a bat file, it doesn't work.
[image]

here, is my bat file:
[image]

Comment: Welcome  to [SO]. You should really paste the actual text of your files and code in the question using the [edit] button, rather than include images of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like php is not reading the php.ini.

Run the command `php --ini` and see if the *Loaded Configuration File:* is the correct one.

You can tell php where to find the right php.ini by adding the option -c:

```
php -c C:\php\php.ini -f C:\wamp\...\mail.php
```

Comment: after specifying the right php.ini by adding the option -c , I stopped getting the warning message: failed to connect to mailserver ..... but a new pop up open with the title (C:\Wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe) and I receive no email

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working on Mac and don't have a PC or Windows virtual machine right now to test it, but the guide in this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php#77499) might help. See that the php.ini section for mail is simulating you're working on Unix. I'm assuming you have WAMP installed.